# how to retrieve last inserted nrecord for a particular ID in my sql

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve the last inserted record in My sql? For example the ID 102 has three records and i have to retrieve the last inserted record

Comment: Any timestamp in the table？ Or is there an auto_increment pk?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose id is your auto_increment pk, and r_id is the 'ID' value for a record.

```
select * from [table] where r_id=102 order by id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: i have to get distinct row in my query distinct is not working

Comment: select distinct Im.IntEnquiryID,Em.EnquiryName from interactionmaster as Im join enquirymaster as Em on Im.intEnquiryID=Em.ID where Im.intDate between 12/3/2011 and 30/3/2011 order by ID desc limit 1

Comment: ya its not retrieveing single record its retriving more than one record if i use group by its retreiving one record but not the last inserted record